# Is there an API to get OS platform at runtime in Visual Studio Code Extension API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We can set different keybindings for different OS platforms in keybindings which take input as `isLinux` `isMac` `isWindows` `isWeb`  , the corresponding code lies in [vscode/src/vs/base/common/platform.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/base/common/platform.ts)

But doesnt seem to be exposed through vscode module.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode'
```

How can I get OS platform at runtime within my extension?

Comment: Rather typical Node.JS API, https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform

Comment: thanks, I am using this now. Also wanted to use the one from vscode which has more code to identify web platform as well. Have raised request on github as well.

Comment: Your extension is not executed on the web, but some operating system. So it is meaningless to raise a request.